# Parsing a XML string using JAXB

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd, xml-serialization

I am using the `JAXB` parser to convert `XML` to a Java object. I have generated the `JAXB` files from the `XML` schema `(XSD)`.

While passing the `XML` String , I defined `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='Typetest.xsd'`. So this will validate the `XML` document against the `XML` schema `Typetest.xsd`.

But my question is that I never defined the path for the `JAXB` parser to grab the schema file.

So how will `JAXB` determine the path ?

```
<book xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="TypeTest.xsd">
</book>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable validation on the `unmarshal` operation you must set an instance of `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller`.

Below is a link to an example on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I have no issues  with the validation against the schema.But i am just curious on where actually the unmarshaller finds the path from? from my code , i just pass the xml string to the unmarshaller .Can you help to explain with an example?

Comment: @jegadees - The `Unmarshaller` doesn't find the path.  You need to create an instance of `Schema` and set it on the `Unmarshaller` yourself.  I have added a link to an example in my answer.

Comment: exactly the answer i am looking for..Thanks